# How do I make my TI-89 evaluate a recursive function?

Tags: functions, recursion, calculator

On my TI-89 I can assign variables recursively such as:
$1\to x$ returns 1
$x+1 \to x$ returns 2
$x+1 \to x$ returns 3
etc.
How could I do functions the same way:
$x \to f(x)$ returns Done
$2\cdot f(x)+x \to f(x)$ returns Done
but
$f(x)$ now returns Error: Memory< br />

---

I think that it is because it is trying to define $f(x)$ in terms of itself but each iteration I just want it to evaluate $f(x)$ and return the result to the function in terms of $x$ therefore $f(x)$ would return $3x$.
Someone might wonder why I don't just evaluate this one by hand but I am trying to understand the concept so I can apply it to more complex recursive formulas such as $$p_{k+1}(x)=2p_k(x-1)+\frac{1-2p_k(-1)}{k!}(1-x)(2-x)\cdots(k-x) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CORRECTED**

I rebooted my old Ti92 and wrote you a little program for the symbolic evaluation of :
$$p_{k+1}(x)=2p_k(x-1)+\frac{1-2p_k(-1)}{k!}(1-x)(2-x)\cdots(k-x)$$

I had too to shift the $k$ index ($k\to k-1$) and add the indispensable initial condition (arbitrary $1$ for $k\le 1$).

The resulting function is (use  [APPS] [7] [3] to create it!) :

```
p(k,xx)
Func
   Local a,i
   If k<= 1 Then
      Return 1
   Else
      1->a
      For i, 1, k-1
         a*(i-xx)/i->a
      EndFor
      Return 2*p(k-1,xx-1)+(1-2*p(k-1,-1))*a
   EndIf
EndFunc
```

and you will get (use the keys $\,[\diamond]$ [Home]  for the input) :

$\displaystyle p(3,x)\qquad\qquad\qquad \frac{x^2}2+\frac x2+1$

*Note that in my first version I obtained "circular definition" errors and could call only $\,p_k(x)$ instead of the wished $\,p_k(x-1)$. The simple replacement of the function parameter $x$ by $xx$ solved both problems as explained in the [TI Knowledge Base](https://epsstore.ti.com/OA_HTML/csksxvm.jsp?nSetId=80783).*

Hoping this made all this useful,

Comment: I just noticed how old the question was... You probably found the answer since then sorry,

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. Yes the question is old but no I haven't found the answer yet. I'll have to try that out on my calculator. I also need to look back at my project that I wanted recursive functions for and see if this would work for it.

Comment: @Math Man: I corrected my answer to make this work without limitations. In the TI link added you should find too shorter code when the function is not too complicated. Excellent continuation,

Answer (score -1):

I just found a solution.
Plug in any number into your variable first. Then your calculator will treat it as the older TI- calculators (-83, -84, etc.) would, rather than as a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately as the goal was to evaluate and simplify the algebraic expansions of recursive functions, not simply get a number it was necessary to find a way to define functions recursively rather than variables which I had already done as noted at the beginning of my question.

Comment: Fair. My solution was to prevent the "Circular Definition" error.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, the TI-89 cannot find closed forms for recursive functions. Try Wolfram|Alpha for that. However, we can easily graph recursively defined sequences.

Click `MODE` and switch `Graph...` to `SEQUENCE`. Then go to the plotter, and input your recursive function. For example, `u1 = u1(n-1) + u1(n-2)` with initial conditions of `ui1 = {0,1}`.

From there you may graph your sequence and extract a table of values, which can be used as data to find the best fitting curve, for example.

Comment: I'm familiar with that. What I want to do is create a sequence of polynomials each of which is dependent on the last sequence. I want to take a whole function and use it in the next function.

Comment: THe OP did not want the TI-89 to find the closed form of a recursive funtion. He wants to define a function recursively.